# PHP html string to array with DOMDocument not returning every element

Tags: php, html, arrays, domdocument

I'm trying to create a function which converts an HTMl string to a multidimensional array where the parent array is the tag and the children are the attributes, but if I `print_r()` my function it doesn't return every element.

The string is originaly a part of a big object and looks like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
   (          
    [html] => 
      <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="18" checked="checked" id="80">
      <label class="other" for="80">Label for radio 1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="20" id="81">
      <label class="other" for="81">Label for radio 2</label>
   )

  [1] => stdClass Object
   (
    [html] => 
      <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="19" checked="checked" id="91">
      <label class="other" for="91">Label for radio 3</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="21" id="92">
      <label class="other" for="92">Label for radio 4</label>
   )

)
```

and this is my function:

```
<?php
function htmltoarray($param){
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($param);
        $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $html = $doc->getElementsByTagName('*');        
        $form = array();
        foreach($html as $v){           
            $tag = $v->nodeName;
            $val = $v->nodeValue;           
            foreach($v->attributes as $k => $a){
                $form[$tag]['txt'] = utf8_decode($val);
                $form[$tag][$k] = $a->nodeValue;
            }
        }   
    return $form;
}

// AND I CALL THE FUNCTION HERE:
foreach($myobject as $formelement){
  $convertthis = $formelement->html;
  echo '<pre>'; print_r(htmltoarray($convertthis)); echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

and this returns this:

```
<pre>Array
(
 [input] => Array
   (
     [txt] => 
     [id] => 80
     [checked] => checked
     [type] => radio
     [value] => 20
     [name] => radio1
   )

 [label] => Array
   (
     [txt] => Label for radio 1
     [for] => 80
     [class] => other
  )

)
</pre>

<pre>Array
(
 [input] => Array
   (
     [txt] => 
     [id] => 92
     [checked] => checked
     [type] => radio
     [value] => 21
     [name] => radio4
   )

 [label] => Array
   (
     [txt] => Label for radio 4
     [for] => 92
     [class] => other
   )

)
</pre>
```

As you see it returns the the first two elements from the first string and the last two from the second string.

What am I missing? Why is this strange retun and how can I fix it to return every element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values inside your array are overwritten, thus getting only the last value. Create a temporary grouping array first. Then merge them and push inside.

I improved it a little bit:

```
function htmltoarray($param){
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($param);
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    // get body children
    $html = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes;
    $form = array();
    foreach($html as $v){
        if(get_class($v) != 'DOMText') { // disregard Text nodes
            $tag = $v->nodeName;
            $val = $v->nodeValue;
            $attrs = array();
            foreach($v->attributes as $k => $a){ // gather all attributes
                $attrs[$k] = $a->nodeValue;
            }
            // merge dom text value with attributes
            $element = array_merge(array('txt' => utf8_decode($val)), $attrs);
            $form[$tag][] = $element; // push them inside with another dimension
                    // ^ this one
        }
    }

    return $form;
}

// AND I CALL THE FUNCTION HERE:
foreach($myobject as $formelement){
  $convertthis = $formelement->html;
  echo '<pre>'; print_r(htmltoarray($convertthis)); echo '</pre>';
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XP1gW2)